# Disabling themes in a subdirectory with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config

This should be a simple one. I am using a program that has themes defined in its Web.config file. I want to turn these off for a subdirectory.

I copied Web.config into a subdirectory and tried removing the theme attribute from the pages element on Web.config but that didn't get me anywhere. I got a bunch of errors about elements that are apparently not allowed in non-root Web.config files so I removed all of those elements, but I am still getting the same error.

I tried adding `EnableTheming="False"` in the ASPX `Page` header, the thing that defines `Language=C#`, etc., but it didn't work either.

So if someone can tell me a tested, confirmed way to make this work, I would appreciate that. I am using .NET Framework 2.0 on Server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it with a very basic Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <system.web>
                <pages theme="" />
        </system.web>
</configuration>
```